# using rcparams in matplotlib to set major and minor locators

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, YearLocator, MonthLocator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator(bymonthday=1, interval=2))
```

Is it possible to set the code above using matplotlib rcparams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot control the locator via matplotlib rc. The default is always an [`AutoDateLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator).

All valid matplotlib rc parameter are shown in the example file
https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html.